# Set path to .dylib path in Cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, macos, shared-libraries, dylib

I'm developing a Mac OS X Cocoa app and want to use several .dylib libraries. How do I set the path to a .dylib which resides somewhere in my Application folder? What if the path resides in different directories on different computers or is not existent at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which resides somewhere in my Application folder?

Use `@rpath`. (or `@executable_path`.) See [`man 1 dyld`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html).

> What if the path resides in different directories on different computers or is not existent at all?

Then your app will fail to load. Use [weak linking](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html) or load the dylib at runtime with `dlopen` if the dylib is not essential.

Comment: How can I tell the user that a .dylib is missing when using dlopen?

Comment: `dlopen` will return `NULL` if the dylib is missing or invalid. (And you can check if a file exist or not with `fstat`...)